# What has caused the padding around this div to disappear?

Tags: html, css

Dev tools doesn't show the .pad15 class for several divs on the GitHub site page, even though they have them. The same CSS is working fine for the actual site. I have searched for differences between the two files that could possibly be causing this, but haven't found the problem. There have been a few minor unrelated changes, but the syntax checks out. What is this issue?

Broken dev version: http://briligg.github.io/moonwards/index.html#colony

Working site version: http://moonwards.com/index.html#colony

[image: side by side of styles readout for broken and working divs]

The CSS that applies to both is on line 354 or 357 of main.css

`.pad15 {
    padding: 15px;
}`

Comment: Alright, it was just a snippet from elsewhere that had somehow gotten copied to a line above that class, where i wasn't looking. Heh...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is those DIVs on github was affected by some padding settings somewhere. Try adding `!important` to your `.pad15` css class and see if it helps.

```
.pad15 { padding: 15px !important; }
```

Comment: It does the same thing when i load it from the files on my computer, and no other CSS file has been altered recently. Even worse, adding important doesn't work :-[

Answer (score 1):

From your examples of Google dev tools I can see on the left styles are loaded by main.css but on the right some styles are loaded within the actual page in `<style><\style>` tags, these styles will override the main.css, using `.pad15 {padding:15px !important;}` should fix that.

Comment: When i check it now it doesn't show that <style> part, and i never checked what it said there, unfortunately. Again, i don't know what the difference could be. It does the same thing both loading from files on my computer, and loading from GitHub. And adding !important didn't help.

Comment: Ok, i found it... somehow a snippet of markup had gotten copied to the line above that class, i didn't notice it before. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Add another div outside that div you wish to have a 15px padding around so that the div outside has the class="pad15"